# Local WiFi sync in Mavericks 10.9.3 iTunes

Tags: itunes, macos, data-synchronization, contacts, calendar

With iTunes contact and calendar sync over USB [reinstated in 10.9.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1745), does this change also reinstate the ability to locally synchronize over WiFi (i.e. not cloud sync) as is available in Mountain Lion?

In ML there is the ability to use WiFi as an alternative to USB to synchronize contacts and calendar locally (not using iCloud).

Both USB and local WiFi sync were removed and replaced by iCloud sync in Mavericks.

The question is whether or not both functionalities are back with 10.9.3 or only the USB part.

Comment: What is local sync over USB? with WiFi, please explain. Is it WiFi USB stick or ? as far I know the calDAV and the CardDAV will use what ever active WiFI you use!

Comment: In ML there is the ability to use WiFi as an alternative to USB to synchronize contacts and calendar locally. My question is about whether or not this functionality has been made available in Mavericks with the 10.9.3 update.

Answer (score 1):

Only the ability to sync via USB has been restored.